# QR Scan in Angular

Tags: angular, qr-code

How to implement Live QR Scanner in Angular. I tried Zxing library but haven't found proper documentation for integrating with Angular.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found this, https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner. This one works with Angular very well. With this, you can scan QR codes in your web app. Cheers!

Comment: This is still working well in 2022 :)